# What is the use of def __cmp__(self, other) while using in Priority Queue?

Tags: python

```
import Queue

class Job(object):

    def __init__(self, priority, description):
        self.priority = priority
        self.description = description

    def __cmp__(self,other):
        return cmp(self.priority, other.priority)
```

What is the need of "cmp" Function ?

As from the name it seems it is comparing the Priority with the others.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#cmp

Comment: I believe the Colonel meant [RTFM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM).

Answer (score 1):

As per the [Priority Queue docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.PriorityQueue), in a priority queue, *"The lowest valued entries are retrieved first (the lowest valued entry is the one returned by sorted(list(entries))[0])."*.

By defining the `__cmp__` function for the `Job` object, anytime `sort` or `sorted` (or similar functions) are run with these Job objects, the system knows that the ordering must be based on the `.priority` attribute of these objects.

So when the consumer of these jobs tries to get a job out of the priority queue, the queue will pass it the job with the lowest `.priority` value.  Without `__cmp__` defined, the ordering of the jobs will be arbitrary (I think in CPython it's going to end up based on the memory location of each object, which can be in no apparent order).